# What is co-Turing recognizable, how do I prove complement of two languages is decidable using Co-Turing concepts?

Tags: theory, computation-theory, turing-machines

Let L1 and L2 be two languages such that there exist no string w that belongs to both L1 and L2.
I am struggling on How to Prove that, if L1 and L2 are both co-Turing-recognizable, there exists a decidable language A such that L1 ⊆ A and L2 ⊆ A`.
A` - complement of A

Answer (score 0):

We may assume that neither of `L1` nor `L2` is decidable, since if either is, the solution is trivial (let `A = L1` or `A' = L2` if `L1` or `L2` is decidable, respectively). In particular, neither `L1` nor `L2` is Turing-recognizable.

Given that, `A` must be equal to the set `L1` with some more elements added to it (it must have at least the elements in `A1` if it is to be a superset). Because `L2` is a subset of `A'`, none of the elements added to `L1` to form `A` can be in `L2`. Furthermore, we must add infinitely many items since adding finitely many items cannot render `A` decidable where `L1` is not.

Split up the stuff not in `L1` or `L2` into two languages `R1` and `R2` such that those languages have nothing in common and every string is in exactly one of `L1`, `L2`, `R1` and `R2`. Furthermore, choose `R1` and `R2` so that `R1` is co-Turing-recognizable, `R2` is Turing-recognizable and both sets are infinite. Let `A = L1 U R1`. Now, `A' = L2 U R2`.

1. `A` is co-Turing-recognizable. If `w` is not in `L1`, we can eventually recognize that fact. If `w` is not in `R1`, we can decide that fact. Therefore, we can eventually recognize that `w` is in neither.
2. `L2` is c-Turing-recognizable. If `w` is not in `L2`, we can eventually recognize that fact. If it's not in `L2`, then it's either in `A` or `R2`. But we can decide whether `w` is in `R2` since `R2` is decidable. Therefore, if we recognize that `w` is not in `L2` and decide it's not in `R2`, we have recognized that `w` is in `A`. Therefore, `A` is Turing-recognizable.
3. We saw in 1 that `A` is co-Turing-recognizable and in 2 that `A` is Turing-recognizable. Therefore, `A` is decidable. Consequently, `A'` is decidable.

Note that we sort of waved our hands there when we "split up" stuff not in `L1` or `L2` into two infinite languages, one co-Turing-recognizable and the other co-Turing-recognizable. It seems like it's safe to assume that in any infinite language, there must be exist a proper subset of that language which is recognizable but not decidable. You might want to look that up and/or prove separately to verify. Proof idea: the elements of any infinite set could be put into lexicographic order, in which case there is a bijection with the language of all strings over the alphabet; because there are such recognizable but undecidable languages over the set of all strings, so too must there be recognizable but undecidable languages over this set of strings. It might be important to note that (L1 U L2)' is recognizable as that might be required to make any argument rigorous.